# Regex to extract angular path without forwardslashes

Tags: angularjs, regex, path, angular-ui-router, location

I have following routes in my angular app:

```
#/categoryevents
#/categoryevents/event/5
#/categoryevents/event/5/3
```

or for example:

```
#/events
#/events/get/5
#/events/get/5/3
```

I need regex to extract only pathname between **'#/'** and first upcoming **'/'**. From above examples, it should extract **"categoryevents"** or **"events"**.

I already tried, but my regex matched "categoryevents/", "categoryevents/event/5" or "events/get/5", I mean it matched everything after "#/".

Answer (score 0):

Try this `#\/([a-z]+)`, this will match only letters after the slash and stop at the first non letter.
You can use something like https://regex101.com/ to test your expressions

Comment: It is useful as long as the word after "#/" is contained only of letters [a-z] and it does work in my case. But for the sake of certainty, it would be better to make regex to match everything till first upcoming "/" after "#/".

Comment: Try this `#\/([^\/\s]+)`, it matches anything but a forward slash or whitespace